# Extending a Table with Users' Individual Preferred Custom Properties

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

What is the most performance-efficient way to allow end-users to add custom properties to a core table used by an application.

For example, core table `FRIENDS` has columns `ID`, `FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, and `BIRTHDAY`.

User 1 wants to also track additional properties `FAVORITE_COLOR` and `LUCKY_NUMBER`, but User 2 wants to also track different additional properties `ZODIAC_SIGN`, `MARRIAGE_ANNIVERSRY_DATE`, and `GOLF_HANDICAP`.

I have implemented two approaches for testing:

1. First approach: Add a new table `FRIENDS_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES` having an FK pointer back to `FRIENDS` and two columns for value pairs (`KEY` and `VALUE` such as **FAVORITE_COLOR**, **YELLOW**). This approach potentially requires many queries on `FRIENDS_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES` to retrieve all the properties for a given friend.
2. Second approach: Add extension columns right on the `FRIENDS` table itself of varying data types for `CUSTOM_1`, `CUSTOM_2`, ... `CUSTOM_64`, etc. If a user needed more custom properties than there were columns, my design would "spill over" to approach 1.  This approach is more brute force but easily results in many NULL column values on many rows.

I can make both work but am unsure the best approach to determine which is better (or if there is already a clear best practice one way or another).

Thanks.

Comment: If you go with approach number one (I have done something similar/same thing in past but with MSSQL) and I was able to write a single query to pull back all the data and I didnt need multiple queries.  Approach number 2 I would not go with.  Since what I did was in MSSQL, the code may not translate/convert to MYSQL, but it was possible.

Comment: I think you're almost obliged to go with an EAV. But consider creating a different table for each *type* of attribute - so you have a table for date type attributes, a table for decimal type attributes, etc.

Comment: You could also just use a `JSON` field for this.

Comment: Beware of EAV!  Follow the tag I added.

Answer (score 1):

Approach number one is called [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) as Rick James noted in the comments. It can do the job, but you sacrifice lots of useful features of SQL, like data types and constraints. See [EAV FAIL](https://karwin.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/21/eav-fail/) for some of my writing on this.

You wrote something about running "many queries" but there's no advantage to doing that. You should plan on fetching the set of custom properties for a user in one query, and saving it to a map object in your client application.

The latter approach number two is incomplete. You would also need to store some kind of metadata so you know that for user 1, `CUSTOM_1` means "Favorite Color" and `CUSTOM_2` means "Lucky Number" and so on. Where do you plan to store the meaning of each column per user?

At least with the EAV design, each attribute comes with a key, so you know exactly what it means. And EAV allows for an unlimited number of properties, because each property gets a new row.

Ultimately, any design that allow for "user-defined properties" conflicts with principles of relational databases. Your columns no longer have any concept of a *type*. Read a book like [SQL and Relation Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491941170) to understand more about this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance on this. The recommendation in the comments to implement a JSON-type column seems a balanced approach. Do you have specific thoughts on this?  I really appreciate your thoughtful info. above. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm growing to be suspicious of using JSON in MySQL. Like the old joke: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems._ The same applies to using JSON in MySQL.

Comment: You might like to watch my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKZsb1t21UA). It's not impossible, but you should go into it with awareness of the pitfalls.

Comment: The video presentation was very helpful, thank you. I noticed your recommendation to allow the application (and not MySQL) decode JSON structures. Is there a resource you could point me to for studying how to query/filter data within a MySQL JSON structure, particularly if such query spans both structured data (traditional columns) and semi-structured data (JSON)?  Thank you again, I promise this will be my last question.

Comment: I recommend not to filter on JSON fields. If you need to do some filtering, store that as a real column, not a field in a JSON document. In general, if you reference a JSON column in your `WHERE` clause, you're probably in trouble.